# Сохранить список зависимых объектов в файл

Tags: c#, сериализация

Мне дана задача реализовать программу для 2d-визуализации любой звёздной системы в целом и Солнечной системы в частности. Основная часть программы готова, однако мне также необходимо реализовать возможность подгружать систему из файла и сохранять её текущее состояние в файл, и именно здесь возникла загвоздка.
Проблема в том, что мне нужно сохранить зависимости объектов при сохранении, то есть планеты должны относиться к одной и той же звезде, спутники также должны правильно относиться к планетам.
Для большей понятности приведу иерархию классов своей программы:

```
class Star
{
    //...
}
class Planet
{
    Star center; //Звезда, вокруг которой вращается планета
    //...
}
class Satellite
{
    Planet center; //Планета, вокруг которой вращается спутник
    //...
}
```

Отсюда видно, что все три объекта связаны, и эту связь мне нужно сохранить при сохранении в файл (прошу прощения за тавтологию).
Двоичная сериализация позволяет это сделать, но в таком случае теряется возможность удобно создавать произвольные системы.
Xml-сериализация имеет удобную иерархическую структуру, позволяет просто создавать произвольные системы, но она не сохраняет зависимости объектов, вместо ссылки на нужный объект в поле просто создаётся экземпляр класса конструктором по умолчанию, что не есть хорошо.
Как поступить в этом случае? Есть ли какие-то простые варианты решения проблемы, или же необходимо пересмотреть структуру классов?

Comment: а надо только солнечную систему, или планируется расширение задачи? и надо будет работать с астеройдами, поясом койпера, и т.д.? если так, то надо пересмотреть структуру и способ хранения  данных.

Comment: @Stack нет, работы с астероидами, поясами и т.п. не будет, только система из звезды и планет со спутниками.

Comment: Вы можете добиться этого с помощью DataContractSerializer, используя свойство PreserveObjectReferences. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617528/net-xml-serialization-storing-reference-instead-of-object-copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании XML сериализации используйте следующую структуру

```
public class Star
{
    public IEnumerable<Planet> Planets{get;set;}
    //...
}
public class Planet
{
    public IEnumerable<Satellite> Satellites {get;set;}
    //...
}
public class Satellite
{
    //...
}
```

Данная структура позволяет раскрутить объекты от более крупного к более мелкому. В вашей структуре каждая планета или же каждый спутник будет иметь экземпляр более крупного объекта, что не очень хорошо для размера хранилища. А так же не будет прямой связи между объектами